Kafka-reactor to read the same kafka message again if message processing failed
When reading from kafka I want a guarantee that my kafka message is stored successfully in the database before I process the next message from kafka. I use java-spring kafka-reactor. Here is a simple example below.
kafkaReceiver
        .receive()
        .delayUntil(record -> saveInDb(record.value())
                .doOnNext(v -> record.receiverOffset().commit()
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                        .subscribe()))
        .retry()
        .subscribe();

private Mono<Notififcation> saveInDb(Dto message) {
        // save in database here
}

If saveInDb operation failes (for example, due to optimistic locks, etc.), then kafkaReceiver closes KafkaConsumer. But .retry() will make a brand-new KafkaConsumer to be created. The new KafkaConsumer will read the same message again (as it was not committed) and will try to save to the database.
What I am worried about is that we close and recreate a KafkaConsumer each time saveInDb failes. It looks for me as an overhead in closing-recreation opeartion. Say if the database is unavailable for some time, we will close-recreate KafkaConsumer  many times.
Is there a way in kafka-reactor to set offset manually and start reading from this offset without failing the whole subscription? So I would be able to read the same message again and again (if in my case saving to db failed).

It looks like there is no way to force kafka-reactor to freeze kafka consumer on the same offset. I have tried this solution with consumer.seek(offest).
kafkaReceiver
        .receive()
        .delayUntil(record -> saveInDb(record.value())
                .doOnNext(v -> record.receiverOffset().commit()
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                        .subscribe()))
                 .onErrorResume(exception -> {
                     log.info("Failed to save kafka messages in db.");
                     return kafkaReceiver.doOnConsumer(consumer -> {
                        long currentOffset = record.receiverOffset().topicPartition().offset()
                        consumer.seek(currentOffset);
                        return Notififcation.EMPTY;
                     }
                  })
        .retry()
        .subscribe();

But unfortunately this solution is not stable - though the consumer sets the next offset back to the current offset (via consumer.seek(currentOffset)) but sometimes (especially under the load) it does not have time to set it and a new record arrives from the poll method with the offset after currentOffset.

I think, Kafka is missing X/OpenXA support for real exactly-once-semantics. I think, the best you can do is having an idempotent sink, i.e. design the database in a way that duplicate insertion is ignored.

The strategy of closing a Kafka consumer and creating a new one upon failure is aimed at avoiding the overhead associated with diagnosing and resolving issues. Finding the root cause and taking appropriate action can be time-consuming, and often, the resolution involves creating a new consumer anyway.
By directly creating a new consumer when something goes wrong, Kafka can bypass the complexity and potential delays of troubleshooting, ensuring a quicker recovery. This approach also ensures that the last processed offset is saved, preventing message loss and maintaining data integrity.
In essence, promptly creating a new consumer minimizes load and delays, maintaining efficient and reliable consumption.

Matches my experience, too.

Will kafka-broker not give us a ban (refuse to connect) if we close and recreate a consumer quite often for some time?

Kafka brokers do not impose bans or refuse connections for clients (consumers or producers) that frequently connect and disconnect.
